# Is it Riemann-integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ define

\begin{align}
f(x)= 
\begin{cases} 
\sin(1/x) &   \text{ if } &    x\neq 0\\
1 & \text{ if } & x=0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
My question is, is $f$ Riemann-integrable?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've edited your post, is it okay?

Comment: Yes, of course. I saw your questions. I will "watch" you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any bounded function in $[a,b]$ which is Riemann-integrable in any $[c,b]$ for $a<c<b$ is Riemann-integrable $[a,b]$. Here is a hint to show this general property. Assume that $m\leq f\leq M$ in $[a,b]$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Then take $a<c<b$ such that $(M-m)(c-a)<\epsilon/2$. Now show that there is a partition of $[a,b]$ such that the upper and lower integrals of $f$ with respect to $P$, i.e. $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$ satisfy $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon.$$

Comment: If I want to show that now, do I have to write more or is that enought?

Comment: Well, it's a theorem.  If you haven't seen the theorem, you'll need to prove it.  It's not very hard from the definition of Riemann-integrable.

Comment: @rab99 I gave you a hint to show the property.

Comment: I know. That's why I said Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be bounded and $M$ the set of points in $[a,b]$ in which $f$ is not continuous. If $M$ is finite, then $f$ is Riemann-integrable.